# User access level

Tags: sharing, profile, roles

I want to create 2 users in SF who should not be able to see each other's records. These 2 users should be of same role. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by navigating through `Setup -> Security Controls -> Sharing Settings`, edit the org wide defaults, find your object and change it to `private`.

More on [Organisation Wide Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_owd_about.htm&language=en_US) and [Sharing](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm)